# Stuck with Faraday in rspec

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec

I'm trying to write a test calling an API using Faraday with RSpec. The calling is in the .execute method and it works normally in production, but in test, I'm stuck with this error:

```
Failure/Error: @response ||= conn.post '/oauth/token', @params

     Faraday::ConnectionFailed:
       Failed to open TCP connection to :80 (Connection refused - connect(2) for nil port 80)
```

And the test is like this

```
it 'access_token should not be nil' do
      @auth = AuthenticateService.new(params)
      auth_exec = @auth.execute
      access_token = auth_exec[:access_token]
      expect(access_token.present?).not_to be_empty
    end
```

Do I need to configure something to make Faraday works with test?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's actually trying to call a outsider request.
In you case there are two solutions:

### Mock what is calling outside:

```
before do
  allow_any_instance_of(AuthenticateService).to receive(:execute).and_return(access_token: 'some token')
end
```

### Record a real call (I like it :))

> You can try a gem [vcr](https://github.com/vcr/vcr). It records your external request into a `cassette` and on spec run it plays back.

Cheers!

Comment: Where should I add "before do ..." ?

Comment: in your `spec` file :)

Comment: I got this error: `NameError:
       uninitialized constant AuthenticateService`

Comment: include AuthenticateService

Answer (score 0):

Because in test mode, you did's set the `url`,I can replay the exact error in my pry console:

```
> conn = Faraday.new();
> conn.post '/oauth/token';
Faraday::ConnectionFailed: Connection refused - connect(2) for nil port 80
from /home/fangxing/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.2/lib/ruby/2.2.0/net/http.rb:879:in `initialize'
```

I think in your project somewhere,  configured a  variable `url` for Faraday, and you did't configure it in test mode.

Answer (score 0):

There is also something called Webmock, which mocks the API call and returns a response that you predefined. You should look into it!

I like it a lot better than VCR, which could be nasty when dealing with a lot of data or multiple API calls.

Answer (score 0):

My solution to a similar problem:

```
stub_request(method, url).with(
  headers: { 'Authorization' => /Basic */ }
).to_return(
  status: status, body: 'stubbed response', headers: {}
)
```

you can tighten verification by replacing:

```
/Basic */ -> "Basic #{your_token}"
```